# Google Vision API call via Browser for Document Text Detection from File stored in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

API call from the browser (React with Firebase auth) to the Google Vision API in order to get the content of a .pdf file which is stored in the Firestore database. The result should be stored as .json in Firestore. A service account was created and it has system wide access. The expected response looks like this:

```
    {
      "name": "projects/usable-auth-library/operations/1efec2285bd442df"
    }
```

The response I get is a 403 which indicates that something in the authenication process went wrong. In Firestore no .json with the text content is created.

The function for the call looks like this:

```
  const test = () => {
    fetch("https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/files:asyncBatchAnnotate", {
      method: "post",
      requests: [
        {
          inputConfig: {
            gcsSource: {
              uri: "gs://XXXX.appspot.com/images/XXXX.pdf"
            },
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
          },
          features: [
            {
              type: "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
            }
          ],
          outputConfig: {
            gcsDestination: {
              uri: "gs://XXXX.appspot.com/images/output"
            },
            batchSize: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }).then(res => console.log(res))
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or is there a React library which handles that process out of the box or a more detailed step by step guide to make such client side calls to the API? I had a look at the npm package @google-cloud/vision but this seems not to work on the client side yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can find and example [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-cli) on how to use the api with curl.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate -d @request.json
```

Therefore you should use your service account to sign a jwt token and receive an access token from Google Cloud. Then you should use your access token in the post request.

> Your application prepares to make authorized API calls by using
>   the service account's credentials to request an access token from the
>   OAuth 2.0 auth server.
>
> Finally, your application can use the access token to call Google
>   APIs.

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

Please follow [Firebase Authenticate REST Requests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth) for an example on how to generate an access token with node.js

Comment: thanks a lot marian for the quick response. I followed that procedure before but thought that was for requests from backends, not client-side. Do you know how to include (syntax) the access token in the request?

Comment: you have to set the authorization header on the post request that you are making form client side. `fetch('URL_GOES_HERE', { 
   method: 'post', 
   headers: new Headers({
     'Authorization': 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' 
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }), 
   body: 'A=1&B=2'
 });`

Comment: This way I get a bad request as response (400). Nevertheless, thanks for reply.

Comment: This was just an example, 400 means that your request does not have the wright format, you should check how to properly format that request, but I am sure this is the way you should do it form client side. You have to get the token and include the token in the header . First you should check your work using [api explorer](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/files/asyncBatchAnnotate). Then you should translate the request you see there used with curl into your  client side programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The service account only needs to have access to the GCS bucket you interacting with. It seems like you aren't using your service account though.

Typically, you wouldn't have the service account or api key in your frontend because then someone could steal/use your service account/api key and you have to pay for the charges. Better to call Vision API from your backend.